# Unable to generate postscript file using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In ubuntu 16.04, unable to view the postscript file created using the python program below:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root)
c.pack()
c.create_text(0, 0, text = 'Hello', anchor=NW)
c.update()
c.postscript(file = 'hello.ps')
```

Viewing the postscript file in a text editor shows a section given below:

```
/DejavuSans findfont 0 scalefont ISOEncode setfont
0.000 0.000 0.000 setrgbcolor AdjustColor
0 0 267 [
[(Hello)]
] 14 -0 0 0 false DrawText
```

On manually changing the font to say 9, the postscript file can be viewed.

How can this be fixed, so that correct postscript file is generated by Tkinter? Any suggestions...

Comment: on Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu 14.04) it sets 9 as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `font=` to set font and its size. Maybe it helps.

```
c.create_text(0, 0, text='Hello', anchor=NW, font=('DejavuSans', '9'))
```

More: [Type fonts](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/fonts.html)

Comment: Thanks @furas. Solved by specifying font name and size.